# Detect if an email already exists in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following in my FireBase database:

```
Users
 -VCVVsqwws_QSds2ADC1
    email: 
      "lo@aol.com"
 -VCVxCaQ_dSwWBC21AB4
    email: 
      "asdasasd@aaa.com"
```

and then the lines in my `.js` file:

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var register = firebase.database().ref("Users");
```

How can I check if Users already contains an email before *pushing* it to `Users` ? I tried to follow https://gist.github.com/anantn/4323949 but the browser says cannot instantiate `Firebase` (new Firebase) even though everything is imported and included.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
var register = firebase.database().ref("Users/{{userId}}");

register.once('value', function(snapshot) {
   if(snapshot.val().hasOwnProperty('email')) {
     console.log("Email exist.");
   }
   else {
     console.log("Email not exist.");
     /* Code to push email to the specific user */
   }
});
```

Comment: Where is `userId` coming from ? @ti2005

Comment: In your example json 'VCVVsqwws_QSds2ADC1' is a userid right?

Comment: @TomRussell - I want to know is that key 'VCVVsqwws_QSds2ADC1' is a user's id or just a dynamic key?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following code *(trigger warning: es6)* if you need to check only one user really fast:

```
firebase.database().ref(`Users/${userId}`)once('value').then(snapshot => {
   if(snapshot.val().hasOwnProperty('email')) {
     console.log("Email exists.");
   }
   else {
     console.log("Email doesn't exist.");
     /* Code to push email to the specific user */
   }
});
```

Note that [ti2005's snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39682020/6719981) works perfectly well but it will load all users and that process will get slower as your database grows.

Comment: Where is `userId` coming from ? @GabrielAntunes

Comment: It's a string usually containing the UID Firebase decided to give the user. They look like this: _434Pv8IVynZRkV7VX5kFahzDheD5_. You can check your database UIDs at https://console.firebase.google.com/project/YOUR_PROJECT/authentication/users